# How to get weekly target from quaterly goal/target in sql server so that the final view containing actuals and targets/goals is in weekly format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[Actuals table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUSHE.png)
Actuals table keeps track of Actual performance of salespersons towards their goals. The data is in “day” format.
I have created a “weekly view” of actuals with the name “vw_Actuals” using group by as in pic.
[Actuals View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORl2k.png)

[Goals Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C362r.png) keeps track of the quarterly goals per salesperson for each year, The data is in “quarterly” format.
The aim is to get a weekly view of salespersons' “actuals “ and “goals”.Should have weekstart and weekend.
We cannot divide the goals i.e we cannot get a decimal answer for the no. of goals per week when we try to achieve weekly view of goals given in quarterly format.Goals here is an undividable entity like opportunities or leads. The data is for first 2 quarters of 2021.

The final view should look like [Final view required - weekly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzvyI.png).

The approach I followed is as follows:
I have created a week table “WeekTable” with weekstart ,weekend, year , quarter.

Joined the week and goals table using a left outer join and created a view [View vw_GoalsWeek](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4tZ1.png)

Created another Partitioned view [vw_partsGoalWeek](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uk4pz.png) by partitioning on salespersonID,Year,Qtr.

Added an outer and inner partition number so that I can iterate through every row in each partition obtained from the joined Goals and Weeks table view, partitioned over salespersonID, year , quarter. I am iterating through each partition until I reach the quaterly goal, and adding the current row in each iteration to another table Res1 until the goal is reached for that quarter, year salespersonID. The while loop runs infinitely.

This approach is not feasible and also while loop is running infinitely despite a break condition.
I have really tried but unable to figure out a way to convert the quarterly goals to weekly to get the final view. The weekly goals cannot be a decimal answer.

Below is the while loop to iterate through the Goals week partitioned view and add results to an empty table Res1

```
Declare @oPar INT = 1       --outer partition
print @oPar
Declare @oParEnd INT = (SELECT MAX(OuterPartition#) FROM vw_partsGoalWeek)      --outer partition end
print @oParEnd

Declare @iPar INT = 1       --inner partition
print @iPar
Declare @iParEnd INT = (SELECT MAX(InnerPartition#) FROM vw_partsGoalWeek WHERE OuterPartition# = @oPar)
print @iParEnd      --inner partition end

Declare @totalOppor INT = (SELECT SUM(Opportunity) FROM Res1 WHERE OuterPartition# = @oPar)     --Sum of opportunities(new column ) added to Res1 table to see if goal is reached
print @totalOppor
Declare @qtrlyGoal INT = (SELECT QtrlyGoals FROM vw_partsGoalWeek WHERE OuterPartition# = @oPar AND InnerPartition# = @iPar) --Quaterly Goal
print @qtrlyGoal


WHILE(@oPar <= @oParEnd)
BEGIN
PRINT 'Starting outer partition no ' + CAST(@oPar AS VARCHAR(30))

    WHILE(@iPar <= @iParEnd)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Starting inner partition no ' + CAST(@iPar AS VARCHAR(30))
    
        PRINT 'total oppor for outer partition before new insert ' + CAST(@oPar AS VARCHAR(30)) + ' and inner partition ' + CAST(@iPar AS VARCHAR(30)) + ' is ' + CAST(@totalOppor AS VARCHAR(30))


        INSERT INTO Res1(salespersonID ,salespersonName ,Qtr ,Year,QtrlyGoals, YrQtr ,
        WeekStart ,WeekEnd,ID_Yr_Qtr_Sum ,OuterPartition# ,InnerPartition#,Opportunity )(
        SELECT *,1 AS Opportunity FROM vw_partsGoalWeek WHERE OuterPartition# = @oPar AND InnerPartition# = @iPar
        )

        PRINT 'total oppor for outer partition after new insert ' + CAST(@oPar AS VARCHAR(30)) + ' and inner partition ' + CAST(@iPar AS VARCHAR(30)) + ' is ' + CAST(@totalOppor AS VARCHAR(30))



        IF(@totalOppor = @qtrlyGoal)
            BREAK;                      
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF (@iPar = @iParEnd)
                SET @iPar = 1;          
        END;

        SET @iPar = @iPar + 1       
    END

SET @oPar = @oPar + 1 

END
```

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Lots of Images data don't help us help you. If you want to supply sample data, do so as DDL and DML statements. For expected results, well formatted tabular text or mark down tables are fine, but *never* images; we can't consume them and people using screen readers can't even see them.

Comment: As for your question, what is it? The only thing I see close to a question is *"Request someone to kindly help on this"* but [“Can someone help me?” is not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). What is it you *specifically* need help with. What isn't working about what you have? Do you also *need* to use a `WHILE`? SQL is a set based language, so there are really few times you should be using one.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time posting here. Yup, you are right, I am having issues posting it . When I copy the code to the insert code block, it is getting out of place. Will repost it with the said changes

Comment: Put the code in code fences (`\`\`\``) if you're worried about indenting.

Comment: I want to get a weekly view of the goals table which is currently in quarterly format so that I can create a final view of actuals and goals both at a weekly granularity. However, I should not end up with decimal results. If I try dividing quarterly goals per salesperson for that particular year and week by the number of weeks in that quarter, I will get a decimal result. So I thought of partitioning and running a loop through each partition so that I can distribute the goals as a whole in the available weeks partition ,which again I feel is a bad idea.

Comment: Yup, thanku Larnu, will use the fences :)

Comment: The rest of the code involving view creation etc is too big, so just added the part where I am stuck. Looking for any other approach leaving aside this code.

Comment: In order to help we need a [mre] i.e. a dbfiddle. That block of text and code is too much for most people to wade though.

Comment: Thank you Dale, I understand, will go through the link and post that way